# Print debug text from C code into Lauterbach TRACE32

Tags: c, trace32, lauterbach

Is it possible to print debug text from C code (running on embedded system) into Lauterbach TRACE32 (connected over Lauterbach hardware)? Previously we used to output it via UART (serial connection) but now it is not available.

Comment: Why don't you just store the output in on-chip arrays, watch those arrays and update those continuously? Do you need to log values or something? Pretty sure you can log watched variables to a text file with Trace32 somehow.

Comment: @Lundin I need to log the whole workflow - outputs from each function running with timestamps.

Comment: So it sounds like your actual question is how to log watched variables to a text file?

Comment: @Lundin watched variables and custom messages with timestamps. Into file or TRACE32 output window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to print text from the target application to TRACE32. Some vendors call the mechanism you are searching for a *JTAG Terminal*, *Semihosting* (ARM) or *Hostlink* (Synopsys).

This is handled in TRACE32 with the `TERM` command group.

The usual approach is as following:

- Add t32term.c, t32term_memory.c and t32term.h to you project. You can find those files in your TRACE32 installation at <t32>/demo/etc/terminal/t32term.
- Compile t32term.c and t32term_memory.c with defined macro T32_TERM_BLOCKED=1, T32_TERM_METHOD_MEMORY=1, and T32_TERM_MEMORY_BLOCKED_SIZE=256 .  E.g.:

  ```
   TERMOPT:=-DT32_TERM_BLOCKED=1 -DT32_TERM_METHOD_MEMORY=1 -DT32_TERM_MEMORY_BLOCKED_SIZE=256
   gcc  $(TERMOPT) -c  -o t32term.o  t32term.c
   gcc  $(TERMOPT) -c  -o t32term_memory.o  t32term_memory.c
  ```

  Of course instead of just "gcc" you have to use here the cross-compiler for your target with all the CPU specific options.
- In your application use function `T32_Term_Puts(const char *str)` to send a text-buffer to TRACE32
- To use something like printf() write a wrapper function around `T32_Term_Puts()` around `vsprintf()`. Some compiler's C library provides already some printf(), which calls in the end some weakly declared puts() function, which you can overwrite with `T32_Term_Puts()`.
- During linking ensure that the buffers `T32_Term_Memory_Tar2HostBuffer` and `T32_Term_Memory_Host2TarBuffer` get placed into uncached memory.
- In TRACE32 use the following commands:

  ```
   SYStem.MemAccess Enable   // Enable memory access to running CPU
   TERM.METHOD BufferE E:T32_Term_Memory_Tar2HostBuffer E:T32_Term_Memory_Host2TarBuffer
   TERM.GATE
  ```

The window `TERM.GATE` receives the data you've send with `T32_Term_Puts()`. **You have to keep it open.**

`TERM.METHOD` specifies the way how TRACE32 receives the printed data from your target application. The method *BufferE* is pretty common and works with all CPUs which support reading memory by the debugger while the CPU is running. There are other methods available you might have to use if *BufferE* is not possible.

For the method *BufferE* you have to allow the debugger to access target memory while the CPU is running. This is done with the command `SYStem.MemAccess Enable`. Depending on the CPU family you are debugging and the version of TRACE32 you have to use the keyword `CPU`, `DAP` or `NEXUS` instead of `Enable`.

The mechanism allows you not only to send text to TRACE32. It allows you also to open files from the PC running TRACE32, write data to a file, get the system time or start applications.

If your target chip contains an ITM or STM hardware trace module and you own a tracing hardware from Lauterbach (like CombiProbe or PowerTrace) you can also use that mechanism to send text from you target application to TRACE32.

Comment: There's a typo in the example (that's remains very useful). The correct command is (thanks to Lauterbach for very fast feedback):  
; default buffer size 256 byte
  TERM.METHOD BufferE E:Var.VALUE(&T32_Term_Memory_Tar2HostBuffer[0]) E:Var.VALUE(&T32_Term_Memory_Host2TarBuffer[0])

Comment: Oups, you are right. I accidentally used T32_Term_Tar2HostBufferSize instead of T32_Term_Memory_Tar2HostBuffer. I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: T32_Term_Memory_Host2TarBuffer is removed when only T32_Term_Puts() is called as the linker finds no use of the variable in the project.
T32_Term_PutBlock will need to be modified to add *pin(like *pout), and then perform a dummy operation so that it is not removed out due to optimisation

Comment: @Holger , after TERM.GATE, i wasnt able to view anything at the terminal window, though in Memory i can see my text.

Comment: @Holger Maybe you can add what changes would be needed if arm cortex r7 is used.. DCC register method as well